# Optional route (URL part)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

We are developing educational platform. We have two resource types: **courses** and **lessons**. So we do have following URL schema:

```
/(root)
└┬course-slug
 ├─info
 └┬lesson-slug
  └┬comments
   └─comment-id
```

URL to a lesson looks like this: `/programming/what-is-loop/` and comments for this lesson would have following URL: `/programming/what-is-loop/comments/`.

Now we decided that course is optional. Some lessons are not inside any course, some inside many courses. So new URL schema looks like this:

```
/(root)
├┬course-slug
│├─info
│└┬lesson-slug
│ └┬comments
│  └─comment-id
│
└┬lesson-slug
 └┬comments
  └─comment-id
```

In other words *course* part of URL are optional. How to make `CourseRoute` optional, or how to reuse `LessonRoute`, `CommentsRoute` and `CommentRoute` (in fact there is little more)

Comment: What I would do - given this URL scheme, is reuse the views and controllers through the renderTemplate hooks of the duplicated routes

Comment: @MeoriOransky yeah.. but what to do with urls? For example In templates I'm using `{{link-to}}` a lot and I can't keep old route names. I would need to use different route names depending on current route

Comment: You can either use a condition (not a very clean way), or you can extend link-to and LinkView to create a {{#link-to-lesson}} helper that can be intelligent about it.

Comment: as well as {{#link-to-comments}} {{#link-to-comment}} and all others... But anyway thx. Maybe I'll come up with general {{#smart-link-to}}.
Also I'm thinking about moving `course-slug` to query parameters.

Comment: This URL schema is a nightmare waiting to happen. Why not make `lessson-slug` _always_ the "first" route? It just make more sense to me to keep this consistent. Your routes can be `/course-slug`, `/course-slug/info`, `/lesson-slug`, `/lesson-slug/comments` and `/lesson-slug/comments/:comment_id`. Assuming `lesson-slug` will always be unique across the entire application. Then all `#link-to lesson-slug lesson` will be consistent and no crazy url logic is necessary.

Comment: @amesee well.. With your URL schema we have `course` page and `lesson` page but we also need `course-inside-lesson` page

Comment: @H1D assuming that you set up the relationship properly between the two models, what is the requirement for the URL being `/course-slug/lesson-slug` over `/lesson-slug`? It seems its just a difference of a `lesson` resource belonging to a `course` resource or not. I still don't see this warranting weird logic in your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to all!

It turned out that easiest way is to move `course-slug` to query-params. Just few line of code needed to achive  this:

```
App.LessonRoute = Em.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model, transition)->
    controller.set 'content', model

    course_slug = transition.queryParams.scope
    if course_slug
      ...
      @get('store').find('course', course_id).then (course)->
        controller.set 'course', course

App.LessonController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  scope: null # slug for course
  queryParams: ['scope']
```

Because `course` property simply moved from lesson-model to controller no heavy refactoring needed in templates or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're very sure about what you're doing -- that means on UI you have both standalone lesson and nested lesson under course -- you can do this way (hope you understand CoffeeScript, it's not hard):

```
@resource 'course', path: ':course_id', ->
  @route 'info'
  @resource 'course.lesson', ':lesson_id' ->

@resource 'lesson', ->
```

This gives you different routes and urls. Then you can generate links like this:

```
{{link-to "Nested Lesson" "course.lesson" course lesson}}
{{link-to "Lesson" "lesson" lesson}}
```

This way, you have two lesson routes that can not be the same. You can use inheritance or mixin to reuse functionalities, like use the same controller/view/template.

```
App.LessonRoute = Em.Route.extend
  controllerName: 'lesson'
  templateName: 'lesson'   # Or use viewName if you need to define a view

  model: ->
    # get lesson

App.CourseLessonRoute = App.LessonRoute.extend
  model: ->
    # get lesson from course

# No need to define "CourseLessonController"
App.LessonController = Em.ObjectController.extend()
```

For comments, if you wish, you can use the same way. But I think you don't really need to define a url for comment. In this way you can just use `setupController` and `renderTemplate` to render `CommentsController` to `comments outlet`

```
App.LessonRoute = Em.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @_super.apply(@, arguments)

    comments = model.get('comments') # Just an example code to get comments
    @controllerFor('comments').set 'model', comments

  renderTemplate: ->
    @_super.apply(@, arguments)

    @render 'comments',
      into: 'lesson'
      outlet: 'comments'
      controller: 'comments'  # Not sure if this option can be ignored.
```

And your `lesson` template:

```
{{outlet comments}}
```

Comment: thx! Very interesting, but url is compulsory for comments (for example we have to send mail notifications with links). And `comments` is not the only route "nested" inside lesson. Such solution is not scalable.

Comment: You should only use nested resource when your UI is nested. Comments may exists in many pages and it can be considered as part of application status. If you want to express that status in url then query params is a better choice than nested resource. Buy you have to use a canary version. I just used it for the same reason. It's more stable than you think.

Comment: Check this link for query parameters http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/